# How to encrypt the truth table in garbled circuits?

Tags: encryption, garbled-circuits

I'm learning about garbled circuits, and I'm using the following tutorial: [Yao's Protocol](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~schaffne/courses/crypto/2014/presentations/Kostis_Yao.pdf).

I have a questions regarding to construction (encryption) of truth table in garbled circuits.

Slide 14 says:

> For each wire x, y, z, specify two random values, corresponding
>   to 0 and 1.

So I picked:

```
(k_x0, k_x1) = 1, 0
(k_y0, k_y1) = 0, 1
(k_z0, k_z1) = 1, 0
```

Then,

> We need to “associate” (k_z0, k_z1) with (k_x0, k_x1, k_y0, k_y1).

Here's my table according to the values in slide 16.

```
x | y | z | GCT
----------------
1 | 0 | 1 |  ?
1 | 1 | 1 |  ?
0 | 0 | 1 |  ?
0 | 1 | 0 |  ?
```

However, I can't figure out what should GCT values be?
How should those values be calculated?

Comment: Your table is empty but, int the slides, it is full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slides you are looking date from 2014, but some optimizations have been realized since ! 
By the fact that all fonctions can be written as a combination of **AND** and **XOR** gates, you just need to be able to encrypt **AND** and **XOR** gates. Obviously, both can be done with double encryption but look at those two optimizations : [*FreeXOR*](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vlad/papers/XOR_ICALP08.pdf) and [*HalfGates*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/756.pdf). A list of all optimizations can be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/sonka89/www/papers/2017ygc.pdf)

On the page 13 of the [*HalfGates*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/756.pdf) optimization, you have the algorithm using both (*FreeXOR* and *HalfGates*) of this optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Yao, encodes `AND` curcuit as;

- the $x$ values as $k_x^0,k_x^1$,
- the $y$ values as $k_y^0,k_y^1$,
- the $z$ values as $z_k^0,z_k^1$.

Here the upper script represents 0 or 1.

\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline GCT \\\hline
  E_{k_x^0}(E_{k_y^0}(k_z^0))  &  \\\hline
  E_{k_x^0}(E_{k_y^1}(k_z^0))  &  \\\hline
  E_{k_x^1}(E_{k_y^0}(k_z^0))  &  \\\hline
  E_{k_x^1}(E_{k_y^1}(k_z^1))  &  \\\hline
\end{array}

Where $E$ is Symmetric Encryption Scheme, and in these schemes Block Ciphers can be utilized. One can use Asymmetric Encryption schemes but that will be slow, and non-standard.

so, given to keys, only one of the rows can be decrypted correctly.

Comment: my question was how to calculate values in GCT column, i.e. what is E? i found this question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48081/constructing-garbled-circuits, the answer says that E is some symmetric encryption scheme, so can that scheme be an algorithm that computes the values of GCT columns by ANDing, ORing etc. the k_z0, k_y0, k_x0?

Comment: your document already says that "use $k_i^j$'s as encryption keys. You can construct any truth table.

Comment: i mean how is the encryption algorithm chosen?

Comment: see the update.

Comment: Simply letting $E_k(m)$ be a block cipher won't work if there are many gates in the circuit (see Tate-Xu 2003). You either need to incorporate a unique identifier of each gate, for example $F_{k_x}(id) \oplus F_{k_y}(id) \oplus k_z$. And then if you're really using standard Yao (evaluator does trial decryption) instead of point-permute then you have to add extra redundancy to the ciphertexts so you can tell when you've got the right ciphertext.